# What is the Trump's Foreign Policy position regarding professional immigrants from Latin America?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, donald-trump

*Disclaimer: My question is not regarding the actual facts, since they don't happen yet. My question is regarding Trump's rethorics regarding immigration.*

My step-bro is moving to USA with his wife and daughter. He is an engineer (which will have to pass an exam to validate his degree), and his wife is a lawyer who was accepted in an university (I am not clear about which one) for complementary studies (after all they are moving from another country to USA and want to make her degree valid).

What is the Trump's foreign policy position regarding two married professional immigrants (with no muslim religion or blood) from Latin America (Ecuador) / the likelyhood of them being... *accepted* in the US? (With so much media bombing for his controversial speeches, could not actually grasp what would happen according to him to cases like this).

**Edit**: It seems that the main points were not well understood by the community, so I will remind:

1. Quoting Trump's opinion means quoting a media source which fully reflects his opinion, which could be a speech video or a note, with a transcription or digest. Personal opinions should be avoided, except when they are an interpretation over a given media source in the terms I said.
2. This question is not about already legal immigrants in the US, but about people in a Latin American country attempting to become a legal resident (without any prior illegal status in US).

Comment: Trump is opposed to having detailed policy positions.  He feels that they confuse his message.  As such, we could only guess as to how he would react in this situation.  His rhetoric is all over the place.  He loves immigrants and hires them in his business.  His mother and two of his three wives were immigrants.  Immigrants are stealing our jobs!  The system is broken!  You can find rhetoric justifying him supporting or opposing this situation.

Comment: What you said sounded as if Trump was just ranting instead of proposing. So should I take "expect anything" as an answer?

Comment: Trump immigration framework is simple - build the wall and have legal immigration organized in rational manner AFTER THAT. Common sense, nothing else.

Comment: "expect anything?": the administration's policies will not likely have a significant impact on the experiences of new immigrants from Ecuador.

Answer (score 6):

Though this may get down voted, I will attempt to answer.

It is very difficult to find "his" official policy on immigration. There is a large amount of noise out their with one side or the other taking comments, quotes, and tweets and using them to support just about every idea they can come up with. I'm sure if you looked for it hard enough, you could find media stating the Trump will only support immigration of the immigrates are riding a unicorn.

What can be said, with a degree of certainty;

- Trump intends to be tougher on illegal immigration. His "build the wall" speeches and executive order support this.
- Trump sees seven middle eastern countries as a threat to the nation (not trying to say he is right or wrong). His executive order supports this.
- There have been no executive orders in regards to legal immigration from any Latin American countries.
- Close members of his family are legal immigrants.
- Trump owned businesses hire legal immigrants.

I think it is safe to say, that if your family were to immigrate legally, they should not have any kind of a problem. I think it's also important to note that the US (and other parts of the world) are very polarized by the election and actions of Trump, and as such there is a very high amount of "political propaganda" flowing around from both sides. You should take care in trying to weed out fact from theory.

Comment: Even when Trump makes me s*** my pants when he talks, I have to upvote this answer because what you say sounds coherent.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli - you can substancially reduce your laundry bill once you realize that Trump has a certain communication style that is... ahem... I shall politely call it "hyperbolized, bombastic and soundbitey" - which is further exacerbated by the fact that he doesn't seem to care about fine details. If you look at reality, you will note that he very frequently either backtracks from the grandiouse generalizations he promises, or implements them in an extremely nuanced way compared to what he campaigned about;you can argue that it's still not nuanced enough, but that's a different conversation

Answer (score -1):

Trump has no issue with legal valid immigration from any and all countries to the united states of america.  Any and all contrarian views are the result of a deliberate propaganda effort to paint him as anti-foreigner and possibly racist.  If your brother comes to the united states legally he will be welcomed with open arms by Donald Trump.

Comment: So I guess [the press releases on his personal campaign homepage](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/press-releases/donald-j.-trump-statement-on-immigration) are also part of the propaganda campaign against him? **"When I am President we will listen to the people - not the special interests - and get immigration numbers under control, as the voters have demanded"**

Comment: @Philipp where does that say that the united states won't accept professional workers coming from latin america that want to live and work within the system legally?  It doesn't say anything at all in that regard.  It merely speaks of lowering the rate of net immigration to the united states.  Period.  Not rejection of people based upon race or ethnicity or country of origin.  Not deportation of legal immigrants.  Take your attempts at distortion elsewhere.

Comment: "Lowering the net immigration" and "welcoming immigrants with open arms" doesn't really fit together.

Comment: @Philipp neither does your course of argumentation.  If he comes to the united states legally (that now has fewer migrants per year (still the most on the entire planet)) he will be welcomed with open arms.

Comment: What course of argumentation? I am just quoting the man himself. The official press release I quoted above does not make any difference regarding legal status or education level of immigrants. It just says that the number needs to be reduced. Also note that you did not quote any source at all and all we got from you was your personal opinion.

Comment: @Philipp thank you for moving the goalposts once again.  Reducing the total net immigration numbers per year is not anti-foreigner nor is it racist.  Your source actually reinforces my view of the concerns OP has listed.  Your deliberate distortion of the source you listed is at best detestable.

Comment: @Philipp - parsing vague bumper stickers won't cut it. Show one specific case of Trump campaign **explicitly** indicating their opposition to professional **legal** immigration (including from Mexico), please. Asserting that opposition to illegal aliens and legal immigration are the same thing is at best a deep logical fallacy, at worst cheap propaganda move.

Comment: (I won't even go into deeper policy debris that muddy the waters even more, such as distinctions between overall professional immigration and specifically software developer H1Bs, the latter of which is a big populist thing with largely-liberal-and-anti-trump software developers)

Comment: Actually my question was not regarding already legal immigrants but people attempting to become a legal immigrant and the likelyhood of that

Comment: (Just to clarify: as i stated in the question, the attempting people is not in an illegal status, and wants to do all the bureaucracy to live there legally; how will the likelyhood of success change?)

Comment: I'm downvoting because this answer doesn't cite any sources to show that this is actually Trump's opinion.  This is purely separate from any of the discussion about definitions.

Comment: I am downvoting because Trump has said just this week that he will stop all immigration from any countries that have terrorism ties, so "any and all countries" is incorrect. http://www.cnbc.com/2016/06/13/trump-if-elected-ill-ban-immigration-from-areas-with-terrorism-ties.html

Comment: @hownowbrowncow Are you seriously saying that if Trump were to make immigration illegal from certain countries where it is currently, then he is still allowing legal immigration from "any and ALL countries"? That frightens me more than anything I have previously heard from a Trump supporter. Which of his policies are you not willing to blindly follow? BTW, OP's relatives would not be allowed in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_in_Ecuador